# Asking for more info on whitepaper download then on trial sign up

Tags: website-design, forms, interaction-design, user-behavior, conversion

Im currently researching how to handle lead generation forms.

I came across a website which has 3 slightly different forms for downloading a white paper, downloading an ebook, and downloading the trial.The trial download form is the shortes.

Trial Download fields:

- name
- company
- phone
- email

White paper form fields are the same but have 2 more fields:

- job positon
- country

The ebook form has trials form fields + state field.

I can not wrap my head around this.

Why would they have those differences in forms? Does this strategy have a name?

Also, i want to add on this particular site, if you fill out a form once, the info you already entered is auto filed on the next form you would fill out.

So, if you get a trial first, you would only need to fill out 2 more fields for the white paper.

But who is to say that most people would first get the trial, and later a whitepaper? Does this even make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested I found out what this is all about. Turns out this is called **progressive profiling** in marketing and it's a way to ask a prospect lots of questions without the need to stick them all on a single form.

sources:

http://www.hubspot.com/blog/bid/33993/HubSpot-Forms-Now-Feature-Progressive-Profiling-and-a-New-Interface

http://www.4thoughtmarketing.com/Eloqua-Progressive-Profiling-Forms/

Edit:
Does going through all this just to have 1-2 less fields even make sense?

It seems so:

http://www.marketingexperiments.com/blog/internet-marketing-strategy/lead-generation-testing-form-field-length-reduces-cost-per-lead-by-10-66.html

This study suggests 1 less field = 1% more conversions.

Comment: This is a really interesting concept, I'm not sure if it's smart and user friendly, or devious and cunning!

Comment: Yeah its pretty cool. I just wonder if it makes any sense doing all this just so your forms can be 1-2 fields shorter. Have to do some more research, maybe there is data on it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is a good reason for this (which we will never know):

If they have a **different expected audience** for each product, it may be that their business logic has dictated that they need to know the additional information for whitepapers - for marketing or sales reasons.  This actually makes sense if they want to be able to say "349 companies have used our whitepapers to inform them of *X*".

It may also be that each item is handled by a **different department**, and so the information requirements have simply been given to the developers to include.

From a UX perspective, it is best to ask for as little information as possible, but **UX needs have to always be balanced against other business needs**.

Comment: well I assume they have good reason since they are a serious company and are using "clicktale". Maybe they assume, or know that everybody downloads the trial firs, then downloads white papers.

Comment: @user1721135 Not all business decisions have a good reason.  I wish that weren't the case though.

Comment: that is true ofc even in big companies. however since the website im speaking of usually knows its shit, and as i said uses advanced user monitoring, i assume there must be a reason for this. granted it probably wouldnt make a huge difference if they had the same fields on each form.

Answer (score 0):

This strategy looks like a reverse-common-sense implementation. The most guarded of my personal information is my phone number, followed by email, and then anything else from the list.

If I had to do this, I'd tag the most valuable asset with direct contact information of the person downloading it, not the other way around.

Comment: all forms have phone number and email. the ebook has one more field in addition, the white paper download 2 more.

Comment: @user1721135, thanks for coming back to tell us what was going on. Seems like a good lead gen method, to be used with care.